# Как использовать @SerializedName("") при маппинге?

Tags: java, сериализация

Получаю json, пытаюсь смаппить в объект:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(new URL(url), PostRequest.class);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Unrecognized field "from_id"
```

В объекте это поле выглядит следующим образом:

```
@SerializedName("from_id")
private Integer fromId;
```

Почему не работает `@SerializedName("from_id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `Jackson` используйте аннотацию

```
@JsonProperty("")
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!